# PHP error display

Tags: php

I am new with php, but I have already made a registration script that works fine. But the problem is every time I press the submit button to check my error, I'm going to a new page.

My question is how I make that error comes on the same page?

The code I am useing for the html form.

I want the error display in the error div box that I made Any idea ?

```
<div id="RegistrationFormLayout">
 <h1>Registration Page</h1>
        <div id="ErrorMessage"></div>
          <form action="script/registration.php" method="post">
            <label for="Username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="Regi_username"> 

            <label for="FirstName">FirstName</label>
            <input type="text" name="Regi_Firstname"> 

            <label for="LastName">LastName</label>
            <input type="text" name="Regi_Lastname"> 

            <label for="EamilAddress">Regi_EmailAddres</label>
            <input type="text" name="Regi_EmailAddres"> 

            <label for="Password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="Regi_password"> 

            <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="Login_button">Login</button>
         </form>          
        </div>
```

Comment: Use session to store error messages as string and display on same page if exist

Comment: When you click submit on the form, it redirects to `script/registration.php` since your `action="script/registration.php"`.

Comment: is the form is in `registration.php`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want form validation errors there. This is a very common pattern, and the simple solution is to always set a form's action attribute to the same page that displays the form. This allows you to do the form processing before trying to display the form (if there are $_POST values). If the validation is successful, send a redirect header to the "next step" page (with header()).

The basic pattern looks like this (in very very simplified PHP)

```
<?php

if(count($_POST)) {
  $errors = array();
  $username = trim($_POST['Regi_username']);
  if(empty($username)) {
    $errors[] = 'username is required';
  }

  if(count($errors) == 0) {
    header('Location: success.php');
    die();
  }
}
<ul class="errors">
  <?php foreach($errors as $error) { ?>
    <li><?php echo $error;?></li>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: I use the <?php include 'script/registration.php'; ?> And I have the form in same us registration.php then it work